# Getting the Payload within a search result in Lucene 4.6.x

Tags: lucene

I already got the payload inserted correctly within a lucene index as such:

```
addDoc(w, "Lucene|1 in|2 Lucene|3 Action", "193398817");
addDoc(w, "Lucene|1 for|2 Dummies", "55320055Z");
addDoc(w, "Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
addDoc(w, "The Art|2 of Computer Science Lucene|18", "9900333X");
```

the number after a word, is the Payload (simplified for what we'll need later on)

I'm doing a simple `QueryParser` on "Lucene in" as a test.
as expected, I'm getting 3 documents in the result.

When I get the result, I need to get all the occurrence of the hits within each documents with their payloads.

In the end those payloads will be required for something akin to highlights, but not for HTML.

right now I've tried:

```
PayloadSpanUtil spanUtil = new PayloadSpanUtil(searcher.getIndexReader().getContext());
Collection<byte[]> payloads = spanUtil.getPayloadsForQuery(q);
{
BytesRef ref = new BytesRef(payload);
System.out.println("PAYLOAD: "+ref.utf8ToString());
}
```

which is "nice" and all, but only returns the payload itself for each hits, but without the actual word found which is kind of a bother.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the code from PayloadSpanUtil.getPayloadsForQuery() where you replace SpanTermQuery with an own implementation which is a subclass of SpanTermQuery. In that you can return the payload from the super class by enriching it with the actual term of the term query.